# Crash protractor on Chrome

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

I am experiencing problems when running the following script on a specific site. The script works on firefox but on chrome it crashes with the following stacktrace:

```
Protractor.waitForAngular() - Locator: By(css selector, *[id="loading-app-content"])
at WebDriver.schedule (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:377:17)
at ProtractorBrowser.executeAsyncScript_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:232:28)
at runWaitForAngularScript (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:263:30)
at ProtractorBrowser.waitForAngular (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/browser.js:266:16)
at ElementArrayFinder.getWebElements (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:154:29)
at ElementFinder.isPresent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:904:46)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/expectedConditions.js:86:20
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/expectedConditions.js:63:20
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:716:14
at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
```

My protractor-conf.js

```
exports.config = {

seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub', // This is targetting your local running instance of the selenium webdriver
specs: [
    './features/**/*.feature'
],

capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome', 
},

framework: 'custom', 

frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'), // Here it is

cucumberOpts: {
    format:  'pretty',
    require: './features/step_definitions/**/*.js' // This is where we'll be writing our actual tests
},
allScriptsTimeout: 11000,

onPrepare: function() {
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1400, 900);
    browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();
},

 useAllAngular2AppRoots: true
};
```

The test:

```
test = function() {
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var el=  element(by.className("preview-toggle"));


this.Given(/^I open up the application$/, function (callback) {

    browser.get('foo.com').then(callback);
});

this.When(/^I click on add$/, function (callback) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
  browser.wait(EC.invisibilityOf(element(by.id("loading-app-content"))), 30000).then(function () {
        browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.css(".preview-toggle"))), 30000).then(function () {
            browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.css(".preview-toggle"))), 30000).then(function () {
                browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(by.css(".preview-toggle"))), 30000).then(function () {
                    el.click().then(callback);
                });
            });
        });
    });

});

this.Then(/^I should be the best$/, function (callback) {
    callback();
});
};
module.exports=test;
```

Thing is every actions I do (even clicking on body) gives this error. Any other angular page works in chrome.

My specfic question is: what is causing chrome to crash?